# Fill Color Python Graphic (India Flag)

Tags: python, function, graphics

I'm working now on creating the Indian flag in the Graphwin graphics system in python. I'm just missing something with my code right now. When I run this code below, the dark green covers up the white. But when I remove the setFill('darkgreen') from the bottom, the white shows up just fine, and doesn't cover anything else out. What am I missing?

```
from graphics import *

def main():
  win = GraphWin("India Flag", 500, 500)

  pt = Point(50,50)
  pt.draw(win)

  top = Rectangle(Point(260,100), pt)
  top.setFill('orange')
  top.draw(win)

  pt2 = Point(50, 150)
  middle = Rectangle(Point(260,100), pt2)
  middle.setFill('white')
  middle.draw(win)

  pt3 = Point(50, 200)
  bottom = Rectangle(Point(260,100), pt3)
  bottom.setFill('darkgreen')
  bottom.draw(win)

main ()
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from graphics import *

def main():
  win = GraphWin("India Flag", 500, 500)
  pt = Point(50,50)
  pt.draw(win)
  top = Rectangle(Point(260,100), pt)
  top.setFill('orange')
  top.draw(win)
  pt2 = Point(50, 150)
  middle = Rectangle(Point(260,100), pt2)
  middle.setFill('white')
  middle.draw(win)
  pt3 = Point(260, 200)
  bottom = Rectangle(Point(50,150), pt3)
  bottom.setFill('darkgreen')
  bottom.draw(win)

main()
```

I get following indian flag:

[image]

Comment: your code worked perfectly when I tried it too. I'm not sure what changed, but thank you!

Comment: @ChloeElizaGroth i changed coordinates values, only

Comment: is only missing the center of the flag